# VBA syntax- Vlookup with IF statement

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, vlookup

I have two vba query syntax,

**SYNTAX 1**

```
activeRange.Value = "=VLOOKUP(IFNA(IFNA(IFNA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(LEFT(RC[-1],6),'List Sheet'!R2C1:R18C2,2,FALSE),VLOOKUP(RIGHT(RC[-1],5),'List Sheet'!R2C1:R18C2,2,FALSE)),VLOOKUP(RIGHT(RC[-1],2),'List Sheet'!R2C1:R18C2,2,FALSE)),IF(OR(LEFT(RC[-1],2)=""EZ"",LEFT(RC[-1],3)=""STO""),""STORE - ORDER"",NA())),IFNA(VLOOKUP(RIGHT(RC[-1],6),'List Sheet'!R2C1:R18C2,2,FALSE),IFNA(VLOOKUP(LEFT(RC[-1],3)," & _
    "'List Sheet'!R2C1:R18C2,2,FALSE),""CUSTOMER ORDER""))),'List Sheet'!R2C8:R16C9,2,FALSE)" & _
    ""
```

**Syntax 2** (Please note the formula is in a single line in vba, its not in multiple lines as represented here)

```
activeRange.Value = "=VLOOKUP(IFNA(IFNA(IFNA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(LEFT(RC[-1],6),'List Sheet'!R2C1:R18C2,2,FALSE),VLOOKUP(RIGHT(RC[-1],5),'List Sheet'!R2C1:R18C2,2,FALSE)),VLOOKUP(RIGHT(RC[-1],2),'List Sheet'!R2C1:R18C2,2,FALSE)),IF(OR(LEFT(RC[-1],2)=""EZ"",LEFT(RC[-1],3)=""STO""),""STORE - ORDER"",NA())),IFNA(VLOOKUP(RIGHT(RC[-1],6),'List Sheet'!R2C1:R18C2,2,FALSE),IFNA(VLOOKUP(LEFT(RC[-1],3),
    "'List Sheet'!R2C1:R18C2,2,FALSE),""CUSTOMER ORDER""))),'List Sheet'!R2C8:R16C9,2,FALSE)"""
```

Both the code is the same, but vba accepts the first, the second always gives error
error being **"Application defined or Object defined error"**

How did I get syntax 1? -> I recorded it using macro

How did I get syntax 2? -> I tried writing that on my own.

Why is the mistake happening?? please help me understand

Comment: Replace the 3 double quotes at the end with just 1. `& ""` is adding nothing.

Comment: Makes no difference in removing both ""

Answer (score 0):

Try

```vb
activeRange.Value = "=VLOOKUP(IFNA(IFNA(IFNA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(LEFT(RC[-1],6)," & _
    "'List Sheet'!R2C1:R18C2,2,FALSE),VLOOKUP(RIGHT(RC[-1],5)," & _
    "'List Sheet'!R2C1:R18C2,2,FALSE)),VLOOKUP(RIGHT(RC[-1],2)," & _
    "'List Sheet'!R2C1:R18C2,2,FALSE))," & _
    "IF(OR(LEFT(RC[-1],2)=""EZ"",LEFT(RC[-1],3)=""STO""),""STORE - ORDER"",NA()))," & _
    "IFNA(VLOOKUP(RIGHT(RC[-1],6)," & _
    "'List Sheet'!R2C1:R18C2,2,FALSE),IFNA(VLOOKUP(LEFT(RC[-1],3)," & _
    "'List Sheet'!R2C1:R18C2,2,FALSE),""CUSTOMER ORDER"")))," & _
    "'List Sheet'!R2C8:R16C9,2,FALSE)"
```